# How to catch deferred.reject using supertest and chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I'm using supertest, chai and mocha to test my Web API application. I have the following code:

```
it('should return 500', function(done) {
    this.timeout(30000);
    request(server)
        .get('/some/path')
        .expect(500)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            done();
        });
});
```

It should fail. The code which runs in the `get` request is:

```
        // Inside method getData
        try {
            // Get data
            // throws error
        } catch (e) {
            // catches error and displays it
            deferred.reject(e);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    // Other code not in getData method
    dbOps.params.getData(collection, parameter, query).then(
         function (arr) {
            response.send(arr);
         }, function (err) {
            logger.error(err.message);
            response.status(500).send(err.message);
         }
    );
```

It basically does `deferred.reject(e);` and sends the error as the response of the API. I would like to catch the `deferred.reject(e);` part and in the same time continue the chain of `.except(500).end(...).` Something like:

```
catch_deferred(request(server).get('/some/path'))
        .expect(500)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            expect(err).to.equal(null);
            expect(res.body).to.be.an('object').that.is.empty;
            done();
```

Is there some way to do it? I can't use the try-catch block because its not an exception. Also I can't chai's `expect().to.throw()` because there is not exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I never use deferred.reject().

Possible solution: use [sinon](https://sinonjs.org).

You can use [spy](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/), if you want the real deferred.reject() **to run** and you just want to monitor it. Monitor means: to know whether the method get called, with what argument, and also the return value. Example:

```js
// Preparation: (Disclaimer: I never use Deferred.reject())
const spyDeferredReject = sinon.spy(Deferred, 'reject');
// Do stuff..
// Expectation phase: check whether deferred reject get called.
expect(spyDeferredReject.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
// Check whether deferred reject called with correct argument.
expect(spyDeferredReject.args[0][0]).to.be.an('error');
```

You can use [stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/), if you want to monitor it and make sure the real method **not** get called.

Hope this helps.